# ListView items don't appear in the right column

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a ListView programmatically and fill it with a list of data that is determined previously from a file. I am trying to set up the column headers and populate the data with the following code but the result is that the data is misaligned by one column as can be seen in the attached image. How can I make it so that the data aligned in the correct columns?

```
ListView listView1 = new ListView();

ColumnHeader logCountHeader = new ColumnHeader();
logCountHeader.Text = "#";
logCountHeader.Width = 40;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
listView1.Columns.Add(logCountHeader);

ColumnHeader logTypeHeader = new ColumnHeader();
logTypeHeader.Text = "Log Type";
logTypeHeader.Width = 150;
listView1.Columns.Add(logTypeHeader);

ColumnHeader dataHeader = new ColumnHeader();
dataHeader.Text = "Message";
dataHeader.Width = 300;
listView1.Columns.Add(dataHeader);

ColumnHeader timeHeader = new ColumnHeader();
timeHeader.Text = "Time";
timeHeader.Width = 150;
listView1.Columns.Add(timeHeader);

string log_type_name = "";
string log_data = "";
string log_date = "";
string log_number = "";

for (int i = (_debug_entries-1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    log_number = i.ToString();
    log_type_name = _log_type[i].ToString();
    log_data = _log_data[i];
    log_date = _log_timestamp[i].ToString();

    ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_number);
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_type_name);
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_data);
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_date);

    listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
}

return listView1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item string should be part of the `ListView` constructor, it is not a sub item.

```
ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem(log_number);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_type_name);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_data);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_date);

listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
```

And you need to set the `ListView.View` to see the subitems

```
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i =0; i <= _debug_entries-1; i++){
log_number = i.ToString();
log_type_name = _log_type[i].ToString();
log_data = _log_data[i];
log_date = _log_timestamp[i].ToString();

ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_number);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_type_name);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_data);
listviewitem.SubItems.Add(log_date);
listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
```

}
Use above code it will solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide an explanation to OP about _why_ the above code will solve their problem.  All that it appears that you did was reverse the `for` loop, which, unless I am missing something (again, explanation would be helpful), does not solve the problem.

Comment: This for loop reversal will not give the same result, the last entry should be at the top of the ListView.